# handling URLs in django and Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, django, url-rewriting

i need to convert an api written in django to asp.net
but the demand is , that urls are not changed.. means they request the same..

in django i can easily map urls to functions like this

```
urls = (
    '/heartbeat/check/', 'HeartbeatCheck',
    '/change/password/', 'changePassword',
    '/change/ccdetails/', 'changeCCDetails'
)
```

but i wonder how can i do the same in asp.net website??
shud i need a separate page for each url??
or any possible way like in django..
thanx

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET provides routing as well:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

It works pretty similar to django's, actually.